# how to hardhat test against a mainnet fork?

Tags: testing, hardhat

I'm using hardhat to fork the polygon mainnet by -
`npx hardhat node --fork <ALCHEMY RPC ENDPOINT>`

now i want to test on this local network. what is the command?
`npx hardhat test` is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure hardhat forking in the hardhat.config file

```
 networks: {
        hardhat: {
          forking: {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            enabled: true,
            url: `https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      }
```

Comment: Note that with this config, you don't need to pass `--fork` anymore, you can simply run: `npx hardhat node`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your mainnet fork in `hardhat.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    fork: {
      url: "<ALCHEMY RPC ENDPOINT>",
    },
  }
}
```

And you can just type `npx hardhat test --network fork` to run the test in your mainnet fork.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `hardhat.config.js` in the following way

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    fork: {
      url: "<ALCHEMY RPC ENDPOINT>",
    },
  }
}
```

Now in one terminal, run the command `npx hardhat node`

In other terminal, run the command `npx hardhat test ./{Your_file_location} --network localhost`

After this in the terminal where you had run `npx hardhat node`, you'll see the calls made over the network like - contract deployment, function calls, gas estimations, etc.

I have attached the picture for your reference. This confirms that your mainnet fork worked!!
[image]