# Hardhat chain fork on the test rather than config file

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing

I saw that it is possible to test with Hardhat on a forked chain, [via the config file](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117803/how-to-hardhat-test-against-a-mainnet-fork).

Is it possible to do it on the test file instead? In a `beforeEach`, maybe.

I only want some of my tests to run on a fork, while the majority should just run on the normal test network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes

just change your network (add this with your api key to the before each):

```
await hre.network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_reset",
      params: [{forking: {
            jsonRpcUrl: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/xxxxxx",
            blockNumber:14768690
          },},],
      });
```